# Не бытовой, но и не профессиональный роутер?

Tags: сервер, сеть, роутер

Хочу заменить свой не стабильный роутер, чем то по серьезнее.
У меня есть web server, изучаю всё связанное с администрированием сервера.
Однако, мой текущий роутер, выкидывает сюрпризы, что существенно замедляет изучение конкретных вопросов.

Как стало известно из ответов, есть роутеры mikrotik.
В одном крупном крупном компьютерном центре, несколько раз обращался к консультантам, они не знают чем отличаются роутеры.
На витрине только asus, dlink и tplink. Говорили, это всё, что есть. Когда я задал в поиске этого магазина: mikrotik, выдача показала мне не менее 6 моделей.

Нужен инструмент обладающий большими возможностями чем бытовой, но доступный по цене, конечно, стабильность основное требование.

Я пробовал решить этот вопрос самостоятельно, но в итоге понял, что посоветоваться не с кем.

Трафик и его суть не важны. Мне нужна практика, если роутер не подойдет под мои нужны, буду покупать другой, сейчас я хочу расширить свои познания в этом вопросе. Однако в данный момент сервер вещает аудио поток и ждет до 500 посетителей в день. Сейчас не понятно, что в итоге будет на моём сервере, а что переедет на VDS.

---

переменил вопрос полностью, уж что теперь не нравится непонятно. Я решил лишь попробовать спрашивать и отвечать тут. Вряд ли больше зайду сюда. Воспринимаю это как: особенный заходит и начинает плеваться, когда видит, что в вопросе не фигурирует слова "адронный коллайдер", но минуса ты все равно отхватишь, ведь это не просто адронный коллайдер, это Большой адронный коллайдер. Были дельные замечания по поводу вопроса, это приветствуется, но когда не понятно, это напрягает. Я думаю, репутацию придумали не за тем, чтобы неудачники чувствовали себя повелителями людских судеб. Есть одна мудрость: относись к другим так, как ты хочешь, чтобы относились по отношению к тебе.

Comment: Комп, найденный на помойке, может быть использован как роутер с заранее неизвестным функцоналом. Его, функцонал, можно тупо добавлять. Дешевле профессиональных роутеров, но дороже бытовых, хотя смотря что за помойка. Роутеры mikrotik посмотрите. Раньше выглядели интересно. сейчас не знаю.

Comment: у меня есть два хороших системника, один сервер, второй пыль собирает. На помойке видел серверную мамку с двумя сетевухами. Вы считаете, что для практики такой вариант приемлем? Меня одно останавливает, это чистить еще один системник от пыли. Спасибо, про mikrotik посмотрю, это прямо то, что нужно, думаю.

Comment: посмотрел по первой ссылке, что умеет микротик и за, что его хвалят, это сразу многое прояснило. @Sergey - еще раз спасибо! вопрос снят.

Comment: `Минусовать можете до предела. Вряд ли я задам здесь еще вопрос.` и тут бац вопрос: "Как настроить доменные записи и добавить ddns" ;) Ну и так далее. З.Ы. Cisco тоже хорошее железо делает.

Comment: Cisco, это из пушки по воробьями, как я понял, хотя на аукционах много вариантов. Доменные записи настроены, туннель vpn прокинут и ddns, забавы ради настроен. Но реально, задавать вопросы на таких заумных сервисах, это превращается в "драку". В русском сегменте, желание спрашивать и отвечать исчезло. Потому как тебя встречают, понятно, что за сообщество. Благо есть хорошие люди, которые реально помогают, а не колотят понты.

Comment: Кстати о туннелях. В комментах к статье на хабре пишут, что популярный openvpn в микротике совсем никуда негодный. Если планируется openvpn, то стоит 10раз проверить

Comment: Где-то читал отзыв, что openvpn, по ключам работает шикарно. Согласен, раз на раз не приходится. Mikrotik с linux на борту. Еще в одном месте прочитал, что его поставили как раз таки вместо отдельного ПК, видимо там какой-то менеджер пакетов... Кризис, производители экономят на качестве, роутер, смартфон, что угодно. Я взял tplink, с фаерволом разными плюшками, но глючит, очень не стабильно работает. После этого и решил сюда написать.

Comment: переменил вопрос полностью, уж что теперь не нравится непонятно. Я решил лишь попробовать спрашивать и отвечать тут. Вряд ли больше зайду сюда. Воспринимаю это как: особенный заходит и начинает плеваться, когда видит, что в вопросе не фигурирует слова "адронный коллайдер", но минуса ты все равно отхватишь, ведь это не просто адронный коллайдер, это Большой адронный коллайдер. Я думаю, репутацию придумали не за тем, чтобы неудачники чувствовали себя повелителями людских судеб.

Comment: Первая версия вопроса отхватила несколько минусов, а оповещений о правках нет, так что "авторы" этих минусов наверняка не заходят и не перечитывают вопрос каждый раз. Не огорчайтесь. Вопрос действительно стал конкретнее и лучше после серии правок.

Answer (score 2):

Очень расплывчатый вопрос где сказано всё лишнее и ничего нужного. Конкретный ответ на который - **никакой** маршрутизатор не защитит Ваш сервер.

1. Для того, чтоб рассчитывать нагрузку, нужно знать кол-во хитов в секунду на сервере (Чтоб искать в спецификациях возможность форвардить трафик без проседаний по CPU/ASIC)
2. Кол-во уникальных клиентов (Чтоб рассчитать "ширину" conntrack таблицы);
3. Сущность Вашего трафика к сайту. Понятно, что основная доля это http протокол, но коль скоро вы не знаете банальных вещей выше, то может Вы multicast с сайта стримите и для Вас это "просто сайт" - для вещей типа multicast/dhcp нужны маршрутизаторы с опорой на CPU, потому что такие пакеты они обычно обрабатывают "головой";
4. Всё вышесказанное в общем-то бессмысленно, если Вы вообще дочитали до этого пункта, потому что скорее всего, любой маршрутизатор из категории "для дома" повиснет от мало-мальской сетевой активности *к* Вашему сайту, если она вообще существует. В случае же, если этот сайт "для Вас" - подойдёт вообще любой роутер, главное не афишировать его по причине озвученной ранее.
   И это только касательно выбора роутера. Я совершенно не понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду под "защитой". Защита от DDoS'а? Никак в домашних условиях. Защита от взлома? Никак при помощи роутера, только файрволлом. Более того, если Вас атакуют при помощи ddos, скорее всего Ваш же провайдер Вас и отключит.
   Если Вас интересует моё сугубо личное мнение, - место сервера с сайтом в ЦОДе и/или на хостинге, но не дома.

Comment: Так, стойте! какой вопрос мог задать, такой и задал. Я не обладаю опытом в этой сфере, чтобы спрашивать то, на что хотят отвечать!  Опытный специалист сделает вывод и даст правильный ответ! Вы правы, благодаря вашему ответу я могу скорректировать свой вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

В моем случае решением станет mikrotik, определю какой именно. Вот второй попавшийся комментарий из магазина к одной модели:
"роутер не для рядового пользователя в плане настроек и цены, но очень хорош по гибкости настроек и возможностям".
Так же пишут, что стабилен. Посмотрел несколько разных моделей. В другом отзыве, хвалят его фаервол.
В другой системе нашел похожий вопрос, где всё четко сформулировано, но я пока не знаю своих потребностей ))
Самое главное микротик стабилен! 
Вот коммент с хабра (ссылка ниже):
«DrDiza: ставлю клиентам в офис. для небольшой нагрузки — самое то. поствил и забыл. минус в том, что эти клиенты больше не звонят, потому что у них все работает. и платных вызовов у меня все меньше.»

[Mikrotik — Плюсы и минусы](https://habrahabr.ru/post/185230/)

Статья с хабра из раздела администрирования, которая подтвердила мой выбор!

Мир вам, господа.

Comment: Обязательно почитайте комментарии к статье. Возможно выявится недостаток, совершенно недопустимый для Ваших целей. При всех достоинствах всё-таки и бывают недостатки и разочарования как следствие.